# Match Operator behaving strangely

Tags: r, dplyr, operators, match

So I have a data frame:

```
BMI<-c(18,25.2,31.5,19.6,11.1,25.2)
AGE<-c(21,35,45,60,99,21)
df<-data_frame(BMI,AGE)
```

When I use the match operator with Age it works just fine (those 30-50 years old show up as true):

```
df<-df%>%mutate(MediumAge=if_else(AGE%in%30:50,TRUE,FALSE))
```

When I use the match operator with BMI it doesn't (people with BMI in that range don't show up as TRUE, the only that that does was the exactly 18 person):

```
df<-df%>%mutate(Medium=if_else(BMI%in%18:29,TRUE,FALSE))
```

Obviously an 18 BMI would probably not be "Medium" but for sake of simple data in the example...

Must have something to do with decimal places but I can't find anything in documentation or a solution

Comment: Maybe use `between`? (`dplyr` package)

Comment: The BMI is numeric floating pooint ad `18:29` gives integer values and it is checking whether those values are exactly matching which is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%in%` operator is a wrapper around `match`. It doesn't look at ranges of values, but rather tries to find the match of a value in a vector. They don't have to be numeric. For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

letters[1:6]
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
"e" %in% letters[1:6]
#> [1] TRUE
```

Where you have `18:29`, you're creating a vector of integers, and then looking for matches of your BMI values in that vector. That's why you get `TRUE` for BMI = 18, because that exact number is in that vector, but 25.2 is *not* in that vector, so it returns `FALSE`.

It's easier to see if you print out the vectors to test:

```r
30:50
#>  [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
35 %in% 30:50
#> [1] TRUE

18:29
#>  [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
25.2 %in% 18:29
#> [1] FALSE
```

So since you want to know if a value is in the *continuous range* between two numbers, you can either use inequalities:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Medium = (BMI >= 18 & BMI <= 29))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>     BMI   AGE Medium
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> 
#> 1  18      21 TRUE  
#> 2  25.2    35 TRUE  
#> 3  31.5    45 FALSE 
#> 4  19.6    60 TRUE  
#> 5  11.1    99 FALSE 
#> 6  25.2    21 TRUE
```

or `dplyr::between`, which is a shorthand for the inequalities above, inclusive of its endpoints.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Medium = between(BMI, 18, 29))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>     BMI   AGE Medium
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> 
#> 1  18      21 TRUE  
#> 2  25.2    35 TRUE  
#> 3  31.5    45 FALSE 
#> 4  19.6    60 TRUE  
#> 5  11.1    99 FALSE 
#> 6  25.2    21 TRUE
```

It's also worth noting that if you're just trying to get back a logical value, you can skip the `ifelse`, because either of these methods of checking will return a logical already.